# urllib.request fails on urlopen

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, python-3.7

i have written a code which send values from python3 to php but i get errors like

```
Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    req = meth(req)
Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1247, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
val=[('a','1'),('b','2')]   
val=urllib.parse.urlencode(val)
url='http://localhost:8080/new.php' 
req=urllib.request.Request(url, val)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
p1=page.read()
```

This should send the value of a and b to new.php
Php code

```
<?php
 $data["name"]= $_POST['one'];
 $data["nme"]= $_POST['two'];

file_put_contents("filename.txt", $data);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/urllib2.html#data

Comment: @DimaFirst i tried `data = data.encode('ascii') 
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()` the text file is updating but its blank.

Comment: Try change: `$data["name"]= $_POST['a'];` and `$data["nme"]= $_POST['b'];`

Comment: @DimaFirst thankyou so much